# Distributing Chrome flags settings

Tags: google-chrome, printing, group-policy

We're using Chrome as our default browser in our organization, but we're having trouble when printing to PDF. The text is an image and not actual selectable text. Setting the Chrome setting "GDI Text Printing" fixes the issue.

I've searched everywhere to see if I could find a way to publish this setting for the entire domain through either GPO, registry or the master preference file, but I've been unsuccessful so far. I can see in the Chrome source code that a few years ago the command line option was available "--enable-gdi-text-printing", but that command is not available anymore.

How can I set settings available in Chrome flags across a domain?

Comment: For Windows, all settings are in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\Preferences`.